# Word for a process that looks for solutions?

Tags: word-request

I am looking for a word that describe an approach or process that deals with problems and finding solutions. Somehow opposite of a 'purly creative' endeavor.

Example:

> As creative as art is, it is not a .......... process like science that looks for solutions to actual problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Word choices:
- pragmatic
- practical
- utilitarian
(see thesaurus for more...)

Unfortunately, "practical process" is an alliteration.

Here's one proposal:

> Although art is creative, it is not a pragmatic methodology like science that looks for solutions to real-world problems.